# initial socket.join() isnt recognized when socket.room is printed out after the following sockets join

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

[My problem is that my initial socket.join (user that created the game) isnt recognized when I leave the handleNewGame() function. This image contains console.log after each socket.join call I make, I make the initial socket.join call when the game is first created by a user, and the rest are made when a user uses the code to join the game.

```
VERSION 2.3.0 Socket.io
```

[IMAGE HERE! Image containing console.log made after each socket.join,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBp6u.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBp6u.png)

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

console.log("Connection")
socket.on('newGame', handleNewGame);
socket.on('joinGame', handleJoinGame);


async function handleNewGame() {
    let roomName = makeid(5);
    
    const game = await Game.create({roomID: roomName, Players: [socket.id]});
    clientRooms[socket.id] = roomName;
    socket.emit('gameCode', game.roomID);   
    state[roomName] = game.GameState; 

    socket.join(roomName);
    console.log(`Socket ID: ${socket.id}`);
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);    
}

function handleJoinGame(roomName) {
    clientRooms[socket.id] = roomName;

    socket.join(roomName);
    console.log(`Socket ID: ${socket.id}`);
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
}
```

});`

});

Comment: Depending upon the version of socket.io, `socket.join()` may be asynchronous and thus immediately examining the `.rooms` won't show it yet because the join has not yet completed.

Comment: if that was the case, it would eventually show  in the rooms once the async func has been completed, but it doesnt update the room. View the image more carefully please.

Comment: Perhaps your other sockets are disconnecting before you log again so they aren't there when you're looking.  There are many possible explanations.  `socket.join()` works just fine for the rest of the world.  In the future, please don't put diagnostic info like this in images.  Copy it into your question as plain text so we can all see it more clearly and so it can be searched and indexed and accessible to those using screen readers, etc...  Also, if you log `roomName` it would help to know what to look for in the console output.

Comment: You can also log `socket.rooms` and see what that shows.

Comment: In looking at your log output, I think it shows what it should for the first entry.  Since it's an image, I can't copy out of it, but the first Connection logs what I would expect for `console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);`.  It shows two rooms.  One has a room name that is the same as the socket.id.  That is expected as every socket is placed by itself in a room with the name of its `socket.id`.  And, it shows one other room that it is also in with the room name of `s4WpA` which I'm guessing is the output from `let roomName = makeid(5);`.

Comment: My problem was I didnt realize that if a client entered a different page, his socket would disconnect?

Comment: Yes, all resources from a web page are released and cleaned up whenever the browser goes to a new page.  So, I'm guessing there were some disconnect messages that showed up when you logged everything?